# Finding contacts with no activities in the last 18 months- using searchkit

Tags: searchkit

I'm trying to use search kit to find contacts who have had no contact with our organisation in the last 18 months.

Building this as a contact search, and then searching on contact activities

So date of last activity was more than 18 months ago.

What's the best way to build the query?

---

edit

---

Think I've figured it, I've searched for 2 contact activities

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically got it. You want Contacts without Contact Activities if Activity Date < 18 months ago and Contact Role = Activity Target and with (required) Contact Activities if Contact Role = Activity Target. This gives you contacts who had at least one activity more than 18 months ago, but haven't had one in the last 18 months.

You can also, if this is something you do regularly and don't want to update the dates for each time, add an option to the relative date filter option group for the 'Last 18 months' (it should be `ending_18.month`, but test to confirm it works). Then you can use that as your date range for the without (Activity Date = Date Range Last 18 months) and for the with you can use Activity Date is between nothing and Last 18 months, which will find all activities up to 18 months ago.

Comment: To confirm.

People we had an activity with at some point in the past.

But who have not had an activity in the last 18 months.

Wanted to see if I could use Searchkit to build it rather than rely on smart groups, and include/ exclude searches.

Comment: Edited answer above for this.

Comment: I am trying to do something very similar, with Event Dates, but it doesn't work (for me).  The Join effectively returns a row for every Event linked to the Contact, excluding the recent ones.  Just the recent Event is excluded, NOT all the rows related to that Contact.  Or am I missing something?

I can do it by Grouping on the Contact, adding a field containing the MAX Date, and then a HAVING clause to exclude on that maximum (latest) value.  Unfortunately the UI for the HAVING clause does not allow the 'Before Now' construction for dates which I need to package it for my users. (v5.60)

Comment: Maybe post another question with the specific search you are doing as I'm not quite sure I follow.

Answer (score 2):

I have done the equivalent for Contacts participating in events, based on the above but there are a couple more steps that weren't initially obvious.

1. Set up the JOINs as in the original question, but with the second join as With(Optional).  Using Without does not work as noted earlier.:
   [image]
2. GROUP BY Contact Id:
   [image]
3. Add Fields as required for the first Join, and one field returning the Event Date (in my case) for the Second Join.  I used a MAX field here.
   [image]
4. Add a HAVING condition to only include result rows - i.e. Contacts - where the second Join Date field is empty.  This excludes the whole contact record, including those with any earlier dated Events, which is the requirement.
   [image]

This both solves the problem as stated, and allows use of relative dates which is a rider that I have added for my use-case, since the comparison occurs in the Join rather than the Having which does not support relative dates.